# Amadeus api List of airport by country

Tags: amadeus

Good day everyone,
Am using amadeus self-service for the first time, i wanted to know if it was possible to get list of airports by their country.
Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Is Amadeus an airline, or? It may be helpful to provide a link to a web site in your question. You can edit your post to add one. Also doing a web search restricted to their main domain for the terms "API" or "REST" may get you an answer more quickly than asking here (_e.g._, `site:the-amadeus-web-site.tld rest api` in most search engines).

Comment: Amadeus is not an airline, it's a flight booking api
this the site: https://developers.amadeus.com/

Comment: In that case, try putting `site:developers.amadeus.com list of airports by country` into a search engine like DuckDuckGo or Google? Or see if they have forums or a contact form that you can use to ask someone on their developer relations team? It's perfectly OK to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on Stack Overflow, in case someone comes by later with the same question as you, but it just seems like Amadeus' own developer site/resources are a better place to start looking. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

We do not have a specific API that retrieves airports in given countries. However, you could use our Airport Nearest Relevant API.

This API allows you to find all the airports around specific coordinates (latitude & longitude). You can query the API with the coordinates of the specific country (like the center) and play with the `radius` parameter (note that the maximum value is 500 kms). This will give you all the airports in this search radius. You can then filter the response by `countryName` to only retrieve airports in the given country. Of course depending on the size of the country you may need to do this process with multiple geocoordinates.